# UsingProductFlavours in Android

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am building an android app with two ProductFlavours say flavour1 and flavour2. Also i have created an android library named newlib and compiled it with only flavour2 by following in app level gradle file :

```
flavour2 project(path: ':newlib')
```

Now in my main activity, i need to check the flavour and if it is flavour2, i need to call a function from newlib.

I think i can find the flavour using the if condition below :

```
if (BuildConfig.FLAVOR.equals("flavour2") {
    // Call the function here
}
```

But inside the if condition, i am not able to use the function from the library.

Can anyone suggest how can i call the function.
Please do let me know if i can provide any more information for this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the code belongs to only a flavor '`flavor1`' then it should be in `src/flavor1` and not in `src/main`

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use different classes in `flavor1` and `flavor2` folder to achieve different behaviours.

Something like:

In `src/main/MainActivity.java`:

```
//...
FlavorHelper.doSomething();
```

In `src/flavor1/FlavorHelper.java` :

```
public void doSomething(){
   //Do something in flavor1
}
```

In `src/flavor2/FlavorHelper.java` :

```
public void doSomenthing(){
   //Do something in flavor2
}
```